# Asp.Net Web API passing user across layers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using token based authentication for my Web API service. But I want to track createdby, createdon informations for all records. So i'm setting `HttpContext.Current.User` and `GenericIdentity` with userId in my `AuthenticationFilter`. But I don't want to access `HttpContext` from my datalayer because I think data layer should not know anything about `HttpContext`.

So, is there any best practises for passing user informations through layers without `HttpContext'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your Principal to both `HttpContxt.Current.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

You then may access to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` from anywhere inside your code, of course even from projects that do not have a reference to `System.Web`.